# Broken seven input NAND, what did I do wrong? It worked for 2 days

Tags: bjt

I designed a RTL circuit (seven input NAND) with open collector output to a Darlington transistor with threshold voltage 2.4 V.

1 mA in to every gate and 4.7k load resistor and above the Darlington transistor I had a sound horn with very low current consumption. It worked for 2 days, then constantly non saturated BJTs. The in signals come from relays.

All in signals 24 V and VCC also 24 V picture attached. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: What part quit working?  Did the Darlington die?  Does the "sound horn" use an electromagnet?

Comment: The sound is active all the time, is 1 mA to much or something?

Comment: I guess the 7 nand died, haven't checked yet though but the darlington is active even though 24 volt is active on all 7 inputs.

They all look the same as the first one with 24 V in

Comment: Does the "sound horn" use an electromagnet?

Comment: What voltage do you measure at the darlington's base?

Comment: hm, actualy good question.

Comment: Haven't checked yet it is just 24 V in and gnd. 

But maybe it could be inductive destruction?

Comment: Freewheeling diode across the speaker? Decoupling capacitors?

Comment: RTL doesn't lend itself to directly implementing NAND gates. Does *non saturated BJTs* mean *horn sounding constantly*? With *relays* (NO, NC, or double throw?) providing the input, wouldn't it be much simpler to implement the logic with the relay contacts?

Comment: Yes it probably would but I concluded that myself after already building it togheter.

However, not much info on the RTL, what do you mean by "RTL doesn't lend itself to directly implementing nand gates"?

Comment: Logic gates usually aren't used in isolation, but cascaded in bigger circuits: Each output should be able to drive multiple inputs with *noise margin* to spare. You can add inputs to an RTL NOR limited only by collector current at \$V_{IL}max\$ of all the parallel transistors and pull-up resistor. In the "stacked BJT NAND" configuration you show, every transistor contributes its \$V_{CE}\$: sooner rather than later, \$V_{OL}max\$ will be exceeded. You can't decrease the output voltage arbitrarily by increasing base current: That will be additional collector current for all "lower transistors".

Comment: If the inputs all come from relays, why not just use the relays themselves as the input stages, with all the relay contacts in series instead of transistors?

Answer (score 4):

There's really only three possibilities.  Two of them mean the Darlington transistor is dead.

1. Too much current through the Darlington transistor, causing it to fail.
2. A high voltage spike caused by switching the "sound horn" - assuming it uses an electromagnet.
3. The input transistors aren't saturating properly.

To fix (1.) you would need to use a Darlington transistor with a higher current rating.

To fix (2.) you need to add a diode.  Put a diode across the "sound horn" with the cathode (band) pointing to the 24V supply.

I think it is unlikely that the transistors on the input side have quit - they have resistors limiting the current in all cases.

The Darlington is connected straight to the 24V supply and ground through the "sound horn." It is in a position where it can easily be damaged.

Measure the voltage at the base of the Darlington transistor when the "sound horn" should be off.  It should be low (ideally 0V, but certainly less than 2.4V.)

If the voltage on the base is higher than 2.4V, then you will need to allow a little more base current for the input transistors to "turn them on harder."

If the voltage on the base of the Darlington transistor is below 2.4V but the "sound horn" is making noise, then the Darlington transistor is bad - you'll have to replace it.

Comment: so, what is happening is that the voltage starts to swing from 0,345 to 0,710 back and forth. realy strange.